# Collision function in c++(SDL2). How do I pass two structs stored in separate vectors?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl-2

I'm making a duplicate of breakout. The ball is a struct stored in a vector just like the Enemy struct. The tutorial(http://headerphile.com/sdl2/sdl2-part-5-collision-detection/) I'm following only gives the example of checking it with a player rectangle. I'm wondering if this can be modified to my requirements by checking the collision with the ball struct.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

```
bool CheckEnemyCollisions()
{
    for (const auto &p : enemies)
    {
        if (CheckCollision(p.pos, playerPos))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Classic case of [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Firstly, I tried making the ball a class but it wrecked the other code. Secondly I tried declaring the struct and object within the function and replace playerPos with ball.posx.

Comment: Code is better than 1000 words. Just show the code you tried to solve your exact problem.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the patience.

Comment: This was my last attempt. I've deleted previous attempts and I can't find much about passing two structs into a function.

    bool CheckEnemyCollisions(Enemy, Ball);

    bool CheckEnemyCollisions()
    {
           for (const auto &p : enemies, ball)
     {
  if (CheckCollision(p.pos, ball.pos))
   return true;
 }

 return false;
}

Comment: So what is the problem? I don't understand.

Comment: This is how I render the bricks/ball.

for (const auto &c : ball)
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &c.pos);

 for (const auto &p : enemies)
  SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &p.pos);

Comment: It's not recognizing the ball position to check collision.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Adding two rectangles from a struct into a function:

```
bool CheckEnemyCollisions()
{
    for (const auto &p : enemies)
    {
        for (const auto &c : ball)

        if (CheckCollision(p.pos, c.pos ))
            return true;
    }

   return false;
}
```